# How to check what template file is actually being used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout, rspec, view

I'm using Rspec 2 and Rails 3.2. I want to check in my rspec test that in some situation specific file was rendered. Like this:

```
it "should render mobile templates" do
 get :index

 response.should render_template(‘index.mobile.erb’)
 response.should render_template(‘layout/application.mobile.erb’)
end
```

Above rspec code fails like this:

```
 Failure/Error: response.should render_template('index.mobile.erb')
   expecting <"index.mobile.erb"> but rendering with <"pages/index, layouts/application">
```

I read that it [was possible](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec-rails/1.1.12/classes/Spec/Rails/Matchers.html#M000080) with Rspec 1.x. But I can't do this check with Rspec 2 and [rendered_template matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-4/docs/matchers/render-template-matcher).

P.S. I found rails assertion [assert_template](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TemplateAssertions.html#method-i-assert_template) and its `file` option, but  this option is ignored by `rendered_template`.

*UPD* There would be the same error if I checked for `index.html.erb` instead of `index.html.erb`

Answer (score 0):

I can't verify it exactly but I think the file extension `.mobile` is the cause of the problem.

Rails would regard `.mobile` as a kind of template engine but not part of the template name.

You can try to rename the template as `index_mobile` to check if that is correct.

I suggest to use more explicit name like

```
pages/index_mobile.erb
mobile/pages/index.erb # This would be better for organization.
pages/mobile/index.erb
```

Comment: There would be the same error if I checked for `index.html.erb`